# Show shut down dialog from command line, Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, shutdown

On Windows 8 if you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> with the desktop in focus, it displays a shutdown dialog.  I was wondering if anyone knows of a way that this same dialog can be launched from the command line as I would like to remap the "ThinkVantage" button on my ThinkPad to display this message.

Does anyone know if this is possible?  Using Task Manager I can see that the dialog is produced from `explorer.exe` but I have no idea how to execute it manually.

Comment: Open a command prompt, type "shutdown /i" no quotes and hit enter key, not quite the same gui but will perform the same function.

Comment: If its just about remapping the key you can use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com) for that, alternatively there are also Registry hack to remap keys. [MOre here.](http://superuser.com/questions/489710/windows-8-tablet-keyboard-has-no-pause-break-key/490079#490079)

Comment: Typically the system power button does this. It shouldn't be necessary to assign a second button. Is it not working on your system?

Answer (score 3):

See this web page:

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-shut-down-dialog-box

---

> Open notepad and type the following:
>
> `(new
>   ActiveXObject(“Shell.Application”)).ShutdownWindows();`
>
> Save this file with any name you like but provide it the .js format as
>   mandatory for example Shutdown.js and pick All files as save as type.
>   Save it to any location but create its shortcut to Desktop.

From there it appears you can launch it how you like, they create place it in a quick launcher folder. So I'd imagine you can invoke it from the command line.

---

You can also use `shutdown /i` which is a bit simpler, but doesn't show the same dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

The command to initiate the system shutdown is...

```
shutdown
```

with these parameters, you whutdown immediately:

```
shutdown -s -t 00
```

with these parameters, the pc will reboot:

```
shutdown -r -t 00
```

There are a lot of other parameters, you can check them out here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/shutdown.mspx?mfr=true

typing

```
shutdown -i
```

will show another dialog (really ugly, actually)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to map this dialogue to a shortcut key myself and although there were good alternatives, the question wasn't answered to the question. I searched and fiddled around and came up with a script.

You can use [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com/) to let any key (Ctrl + Alt + 1 in this case) summon the dialogue with this script:

```
;Summon the Shutdown, Restart Windows dialogue by pressing Ctrl + Shift + 1
^!1::ControlSend, , !{F4}, ahk_class Progman
```

Which actually presses Alt + F4 while targeting the Windows Desktop.

Short instructions:

- Download and install AutoHotKey;
- Open notepad;
- Paste the above code and save the file as {anyfilename}.ahk;
- In windows explorer, right+click on the file and choose Compile;
- Start the resulting {anyfilename}.exe

  Optionally:
- You can put a shortcut to the exe in your Startmenu/Startup folder so it will start everytime when windows starts.

You can find a list and examples of Hotkeys @ http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm

You can find special keys with the AutoHotKey script @ autohotkey.com/board/topic/21105-crazy-scripting-scriptlet-to-find-scancode-of-a-key/
For some special keys you need to put #InstallKeybdHook in your script.