# windows 8 tablet keyboard has no pause break key

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, bluetooth, keymap

I've got a Samsung Slate Windows 8 tablet.  There is no break/pause key on the bluetooth keyboard.  How can I remap those keys or is there a work around?  These keys are relevant to programmers as they are often used in debugging and process interruption.

Comment: One workaround could be plugging in a usb keyboard that does have those keys

Comment: Not even close to a programming question (other than that programmers use keyboards).

Comment: Doesn't need to be a programming question to be here. http://superuser.com/faq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you can remap keys using [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is a very powerful tool for keyboard tweaking and lightweight too.

You can map **any Key** or **combination of keys** to work as **Pause/Break**.

It uses syntax: `OriginKey::DestinationKey` for remapping.

Replace `OriginKey` by the key you want to use as Pause/Break. (say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>)

and replace `DestinationKey` with Pause/Break.

> ^+a::Break

Above AHK script will cause <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to send  <kbd>Break</kbd> keypress.

Learn more about Remapping Keys [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm).

**Other Option:**

[Windows Registry Hack to Remap Keys](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/)   using [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/).